# JSON Parse Error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, spring, jackson

POST Request with `@RequestBody` of `List<T>` -> then I am getting the Json Parse Error Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<"my path to the DTO class">` from Object value `(token JsonToken.START_OBJECT);`

nested exception is

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

Here is my DTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class EstatePropertyCreatorDto {

    private UUID id;
    private String title;
    @NotNull private PropertyTypes type;
    @Null private String alias;
    @NotNull private String floor;
    @NotNull private String details;
    @Null private String commonParts;
}
```

And Here is my controller method:

```
    @PostMapping("/{buildingId}/properties")
    public List<EstatePropertyCreatorDto> addPropertiesToBuilding(@PathVariable UUID buildingId, @RequestBody List<EstatePropertyCreatorDto> estateProperties) {
        buildingService.addPropertiesToBuilding(buildingId, estateProperties);

        return List.of("Once I reach the method I will implement the return");
    }
```

And here is my post request body:

```
  {
    "estateProperties": [
        {
            "id": "8bd050b0-6578-443a-8e22-bf48318734ce",
            "title": "test title",
            "type": "APARTMENT",
            "floor": "5",
            "details": "This details should be aware of!"
        },
        {
            "id": "69786c5f-e35a-476d-82de-1d5833a12818",
            "title": "test title for 2nd",
            "type": "GARAGE",
            "alias": "jamie garage",
            "floor": "1",
            "details": "Details for Jamie Garage"
        },
        {
            "id": "c935f330-eebe-4d35-818d-d2248fc8ca9e",
            "title": "test title for 3rd",
            "type": "OFFICE",
            "floor": "2",
            "details": "Details for Jamie office",
            "commonParts": "Office common parts"
        }
    ]
  }
```

Then I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<> from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to map a json object to a json array (the json sample you provided starts and ends with curly braces `{}`)

If you're controlling the json, you should be able to switch the format to something like this if you want to map it directly to a json array of EstatePropertyCreatorDto's:

```
[
        {
            "id": "8bd050b0-6578-443a-8e22-bf48318734ce",
            "title": "test title",
            "type": "APARTMENT",
            "floor": "5",
            "details": "This details should be aware of!"
        },
        {
            "id": "69786c5f-e35a-476d-82de-1d5833a12818",
            "title": "test title for 2nd",
            "type": "GARAGE",
            "alias": "jamie garage",
            "floor": "1",
            "details": "Details for Jamie Garage"
        },
        {
            "id": "c935f330-eebe-4d35-818d-d2248fc8ca9e",
            "title": "test title for 3rd",
            "type": "OFFICE",
            "floor": "2",
            "details": "Details for Jamie office",
            "commonParts": "Office common parts"
        }
    ]
```

In which case it should be able to be mapped to the straight json array

If you're not controlling the json, you'll need an additional wrapper class along these lines:

```
public class MappedObject {

    public MappedObject() {
    }

    List<EstatePropertyCreatorDto> estateProperties;

    public List<EstatePropertyCreatorDto> getEstateProperties() {
        return estateProperties;
    }

    public void setEstateProperties(List<EstatePropertyCreatorDto> estateProperties) {
        this.estateProperties = estateProperties;
    }
}
```

which should allow the json object to be properly mapped and the list be filled/mapped with the estateProperties jsonArray